# cumsum using ddply

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr

I need to use group by in levels with ddply or aggregate if that's easier. I am not really sure how to do this as I need to use cumsum as my aggregate function. This is what my data looks like:

```
level1      level2  hour     product 
A           tea     0          7
A           tea     1          2
A           tea     2          9
A           coffee  17         7
A           coffee  18         2
A           coffee  20         4
B           coffee  0          2
B           coffee  1          3
B           coffee  2          4
B           tea     21         3
B           tea     22         1
```

expected output:

```
A     tea     0   7
A     tea     1   9
A     tea     2   18
A     coffee  17  7
A     coffee  18  9
A     coffee  20  13
B     coffee  0   2
B     coffee  1   5
B     coffee  2   9
B     tea     21  3
B     tea     22  4
```

I tried using

```
ddply(dd,c("level1","level2","hour"),summarise,cumsum(product))
```

but that doesn't sum up which I think is because the hour column is being used for group by and its being split by that..I think.. I am not sure I completely understand how aggregate works here. Is there any way I could get the required output using aggregate or ddply?

Comment: I don't think you meant to summarize by level1+level2+hour, because then, your aggregation would be different than what you've shown.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a solution in base R using `ave` and `within`:

```
within(mydf, {
  cumsumProduct <- ave(product, level1, level2, FUN = cumsum)
})
#    level1 level2 hour product cumsumProduct
# 1       A    tea    0       7             7
# 2       A    tea    1       2             9
# 3       A    tea    2       9            18
# 4       A coffee   17       7             7
# 5       A coffee   18       2             9
# 6       A coffee   20       4            13
# 7       B coffee    0       2             2
# 8       B coffee    1       3             5
# 9       B coffee    2       4             9
# 10      B    tea   21       3             3
# 11      B    tea   22       1             4
```

Of course, if you wanted to drop the existing product column, you can change the command to the following to overwrite the current "product" column:

```
within(mydf, {
  product <- ave(product, level1, level2, FUN = cumsum)
})
```

Your current approach doesn't work in part because you've included "hour" as one of your grouping variables. In other words, it is seeing the combination of "A + tea + 0" as different from "A + tea + 1", but from your desired output, you seem to simply want the combination of "A + tea" to be the group.

`aggregate` won't work as you expect, because it will condense everything into a `data.frame` with the same number of rows as the number of unique combinations of "level1" and "level2", in this case, 4 rows. The aggregated column would be a `list`. The values would be correct, but it would be less useful.

Here's `aggregate` and its output:

```
> aggregate(product ~ level1 + level2, mydf, cumsum)
  level1 level2  product
1      A coffee 7, 9, 13
2      B coffee  2, 5, 9
3      A    tea 7, 9, 18
4      B    tea     3, 4
```

Comment: thanks! this works :) So when you give product,level1 and level2 as the three columns are you telling it to select these 3 and group by what is different?

Comment: `ave` just applies the function to one variable (the first one) grouped by as many of the other variables as necessary. Because of this, `FUN` must be used to call whatever function you want to apply to the *first* variable.

Comment: @AnandaMahto the disadvantage of teaching people is that it does not generalise as well to new situations, and it's also _really_ inefficient if the combination of grouping variables is sparse (unfortunately it's a simple bug that R-core hasn't fixed).

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thank you for the detailed explanation! It makes much more sense :)

Answer (score 7):

you should use `transform` instead of `summarise`:

```
# you should probably order your `level2` first
dd$level2 <- factor(dd$level2, levels=c("tea", "coffee"))
# and transform using level1 and level2 alone, not hour
# if you use hour, the groups will be for each row
ddply(dd, .(level1, level2), transform, product=cumsum(product))

#    level1 level2 hour product
# 1       A    tea    0       7
# 2       A    tea    1       9
# 3       A    tea    2      18
# 4       A coffee   17       7
# 5       A coffee   18       9
# 6       A coffee   20      13
# 7       B    tea   21       3
# 8       B    tea   22       4
# 9       B coffee    0       2
# 10      B coffee    1       5
# 11      B coffee    2       9
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer...but what if I have more than 2 levels in level2. There can easily be a scenario that I might have around 10 or more levels, will i have to put them in a vector each time?

Comment: `dd$level2 <- factor(dd$level2, levels=dd$levels2[!duplicated(dd$levels2)], ordered=T)`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Is it because I am not using factors?

Answer (score 0):

Folks referencing this now may wish to avoid using `plyr::ddply`. Here is a `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)
output <- dd %>%
  group_by(level1, level2) %>%
  mutate(product_sum = cumsum(product)) %>%
  ungroup()
output
```

Note that `product_sum` is where the new column is named. You could use `product` instead. Then, the original product column would be overwritten as it appears the original question may have preferred to do that and not have both columns in the output.

Data:

```
level1 <- c(rep("A",6), rep("B",5))
level2 <- c(rep("tea",3), rep("coffee",6), rep("tea",2))
hour <- c(0,1,2,17,18,20,0,1,2,21,22)
product <- c(7,2,9,7,2,4,2,3,4,3,1)

dd <- data.frame(level1, level2, hour, product)
```